# Button is apparently not in the class I defined it to be in

Tags: html

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqm3S.jpg)

So as you can see in the image above, the History button is not affected by the black outlines like the other buttons is. Apparently the button is not in the class but as you can see in the code below it is.

```
<div class="container" id="main-container">
    <div class="row main-row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div style="padding-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <div id="topleft-menu">Menu</div>
                <div class="topleft-link-wrapper logout" style="display: none;">
                    <button class="topleft-link btn btn-primary btn-block" id="change-trade-url-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Change your trade URL</button>
                </div>
                <div class="topleft-link-wrapper">
                    <button class="topleft-link btn btn-info btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#about-modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> About/How it works</button>
                </div>
                <div class="topleft-link-wrapper">
                    <button class="topleft-link btn btn-warning btn-block" id="support-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> Support</button>
                </div>
                <div class="topleft-link-wrapper">
                    <button class="topleft-link btn btn-default btn-block" id="donate-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span> Donate</button>
                </div>
                <div class="topleft-link-wrapper">
                    <button class="topleft-link btn btn-success btn-block" id="history-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> History</button>
                </div>
```

I don't know why this problem occurs.
Also if you wanna inspect the site visit; [www.csgoxd.net](http://csgoxd.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other elements have the css declaration:

```
.topleft-link-wrapper:not(:last-child)
```

So your last child element will not have the border declarations.

Comment: Thank you so much! Fixed my problem :)